# How could I make the result for grid based on from -date to to-date?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

In my project i had a grid and two datetimepickers,based on this two (selecting from and to date),display the related date rows in grid, 
here is the jsbin http://jsbin.com/exakic/14/edit

please can one help me

And My tried code is:

```
      $(function() {
        $.datetimepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
      $("#datetimepicker, #datetimepicker1") .kendoDatetimePicker() .on('input keyup         change', filter);
     });

  function filter(){
  $('tr').show();
  var datefields = $('grid');
  datefields.each(function(){
   var evdate = pdate($(this).html());
   var mindate = pdate($('#datetimepicker').val());
   if (mindate)
   if (evdate < mindate)
    $(this).parent().hide();
    var maxdate = pdate($('#datetimepicker1').val());
    if (maxdate)
        if (evdate > maxdate)
            $(this).parent().hide();
  });

}
```

Comment: grid rows is not changing based on date need the result like this http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/zHRv4/20/ in kendo ui  here my code is in jsbin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For filtering the data in a range, you can do it by adding [`dataSource.filter`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#filter) to your `filter` function:

```
var filter = {
    logic  : "and",
    filters: [
        { field: "OrderDate", operator: "ge", value: mindate },
        { field: "OrderDate", operator: "le", value: maxdate }
    ]
};
grid.dataSource.filter(filter);
```

**NOTE**: You can simplify date value reading from the input fields using:

```
var mindate = $('#datetimepicker').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
var maxdate = $('#datetimepicker1').data("kendoDatePicker").value();
```

Comment: I tried this code here but i didn't get any result http://jsbin.com/exakic/15/edit

Comment: Hi Previous code is working fine  when i am selecting with time it's not workinghere is the fiddle :http://jsbin.com/exakic/26/edit

Comment: Yep! You have used Date **Time** Picker instead of Date Picker. Why do you need time?

Comment: ya in my apllication i need time and date

Comment: You did not answer the question _why_? Are you comparing between dates and times, dates is not enough?

Comment: why means in my application having date and time format is like this  (2013-02-18 19:54:13) based on this need to filter and we have data with seconds diference also so filter the grid data  easily by client

Comment: And one more is when date is in this format (2013-02-18 20:55:14) the previous code is not working properly,here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/exakic/31/edit

Comment: In this last version of the code you use DatePicker when declare and DateTimePicker when try to get the value. Anyhow, I'm taking a look into _all your question_ and I'll propose a solution in a moment

Comment: ya sorry for that it's my fault i came to known now actually requriment of my application.

Comment: Ok! the problem in your code is that your defining in the datasource the DOB as a string and not as a date so when you KendoUI tries to compare the value introduced in the datetimepicker with a string it tries getting the time of the string and it fails.

Comment: ok i tried here by giving type:"date" to "dob"  in schema than also is not getiing result  http://jsbin.com/exakic/31/edit

Comment: Check this: http://jsbin.com/exakic/34/edit. Several **mistakes**: the one about using strings instead of dates; confusing "MM" and "mm" in date formatting/parsing; not including "format" in your datetime pickers; your grid variable is `result`. Hopefully last iteration!

Comment: thank you for that but you had edited harded code data but our data is from service data how to write "parse" function for service data?

Comment: That´s a different question :-) You should not include two different questions in the same one since it makes difficult for others to find them and also because less people see them and is less likely that you get an answer.